# How do I get Ubuntu working on a Dell XPS 15?

Tags: dell, nvidia-optimus

I have a Dell XPS 15, (L502X) and I want to know If there is any problem, because of the 2 Video Cards, or anything else?

- Core i5
- 8 GB
- Nvidia GT525M

Comment: This everything you need http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/dell-xps-15-l502x-ubuntu-linux/ .. I am running ubuntu L502x without much problem

Answer (score 5):

This laptop has an Nvidia Optimus video card, so installation can be tricky, however the following 2 sites seem to have good information on how to get this laptop working with Ubuntu:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15
- http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/dell-xps-15-l502x-ubuntu-linux/

See also:

- [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)